# What are the major schools of Kashmir Shaivism?

Tags: shaivism, agamas, shaktism, kashmiri-shaivism

One of the nondual Agamic traditions is the Kashmir Shaiva agama.

**What are the major schools of this tradition?**

Answer (score 0):

> Many wrong conceptions, set afloat by certain great  resaerch scholars
> of the present age, require immediate  correction. For instance
>
> (i)
> Agama, Spanda and Pratyabhijna  are being taken as three sub-schools
> of Kashmir Saivism,  which is not correct. Spanda is that intrinsic
> character of the  absolute reality, the self of every being, which is
> to be realized  by an aspirant by the means of Pratyabhijna or
> self-recogni¬  tion to be brought about through yogic practices
> prescribed in  accordance with Agamas, the scriptural works on
> Saivism.  Different sets of texts deal with them without ptesenting
> any  mutual disagreement on any principles or doctrines. These  are
> thus the essential and integral elements of one and the  same school
> of thought.
>
> (ii) Kula, Trika and Krama are being correlated with  the so called
> three 'sub schools' of Kashmir Saivism. Kula  and Trika are, no doubt,
> two different systems of practice  prescribed in Saivism, but neither
> of them can be strictly  bound to any of such'sub-schools'. As for
> Krama , it is not at all any independent system of practical Saivism, but is an
> integral part and parcel of both Trika and Kula systems. It  is a
> method that forms an essential element in the practice of  the
> Saktopaya of the Trika system (T.A. IV 122 to 179;  T.S. pp. 28 to
> 30). Twelve Kalis of the Krama method are  included even in the
> practice of Sambhavopaya of that system  (T.A. Ill 249 to 254). These
> have been discussed as playing a  prominent role in the Dhyanayoga of
> the Anavopaya of the  Trika system (T.A. V - 21 to 27) as well as in
> the practice of  Cakrodaya (T.A. VII). Krama, being thus an integral
> item of  Trika system, has not been counted as an independent system
> in any of the scriptural passages dealing with the topic con¬  cerned
> (T.A.V. vol. I, pp. 48, 49 and P. Tr. V. p. 92).

-- B. N. Pandit, History Of Kashmir Saivism

(Source: https://archive.org/details/193B.N.PanditHistoryOfKashmirSaivism/page/n23/mode/2up)